# Calculate closest working day in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I need to schedule some items in a postgres query based on a requested delivery date for an order.  So for example, the order has a requested delivery on a Monday (20120319 for example), and the order needs to be prepared on the prior working day (20120316).

Thoughts on the most direct method?  I'm open to adding a dates table.  I'm thinking there's got to be a better way than a long set of case statements using:
    SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To have the previous work day:

```
select max(s.a) as work_day
from (
    select s.a::date
    from generate_series('2012-01-02'::date, '2050-12-31', '1 day') s(a)
    where extract(dow from s.a) between 1 and 5
    except
    select holiday_date
    from holiday_table
    ) s
where s.a < '2012-03-19'
;
```

If you want the next work day just invert the query.

Comment: What if the Friday is a holiday?

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks.  To clarify one thing for others, when Clodoaldo says "invert the query"  its change it to "select min(s.a)", not change the < to >.

Comment: Holidays I'm going to handle slightly differently.  I assume to use his solution above you'd have to store them somewhere.  But they're infrequent enough for us that we'll just reschedule the orders.

Comment: @Dustin To invert you should do both `min` and `>`

Comment: Is there a `holiday_table` in Postgres that I am missing?

Answer (score 9):

This gets you previous business day.

```
SELECT 
    CASE (EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM current_date)::integer) % 7
        WHEN 1 THEN current_date-3
        WHEN 0 THEN current_date-2
        ELSE current_date-1
    END AS previous_business_day
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT y.d AS prep_day
FROM  (
    SELECT generate_series(dday - 8, dday - 1, interval '1d')::date AS d
    FROM (SELECT '2012-03-19'::date AS dday) x
    ) y
LEFT   JOIN holiday h USING (d)
WHERE  h.d IS NULL
AND    extract(isodow from y.d) < 6
ORDER  BY y.d DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

- It should be **faster** to generate only as many days as necessary. I generate one week prior to the delivery. That should cover all possibilities.
- [`isodow` as extract parameter](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) is more convenient than `dow` to test for workdays.
- `min()` / `max()`, `ORDER BY / LIMIT 1`, that's a matter of taste with the few rows in my query.
- To get several candidate days in descending order, not just the top pick, change the `LIMIT 1`.
- I put the `dday` (delivery day) in a subquery so you only have to input it once. You can enter any `date` or `timestamp` literal. It is cast to `date` either way.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Holidays (Holiday, PrecedingBusinessDay) AS VALUES
  ('2012-12-25'::DATE, '2012-12-24'::DATE),
  ('2012-12-26'::DATE, '2012-12-24'::DATE);
SELECT Day, COALESCE(PrecedingBusinessDay, PrecedingMondayToFriday)
FROM
  (SELECT Day, Day - CASE DATE_PART('DOW', Day)
                         WHEN 0 THEN 2
                         WHEN 1 THEN 3
                         ELSE 1
                     END AS PrecedingMondayToFriday
   FROM TestDays) AS PrecedingMondaysToFridays
LEFT JOIN Holidays ON PrecedingMondayToFriday = Holiday;
```

You might want to rename some of the identifiers :-).