# How to find the last 'working' day of last month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Is there a way to find the last working day of last month? I know I can get last day of last month with `SELECT (date_trunc('month', now())::date - 1)`, but how do I get the last "weekday"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate closest working day in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743810/calculate-closest-working-day-in-postgres)

Comment: Feed this last day of the month to the query in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743810/calculate-closest-working-day-in-postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piggy-backing off of Gordon's answer, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT (
    date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day' -
    (case extract(dow from date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day')
         when 0 then 2
         when 6 then 1
         else 0
      end) * interval '1 day'
)::date as last_weekday_in_last_month;
```

Assuming your weekends are 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday). It uses OP's original logic to find the last date of the last month, then Gordon's `CASE` logic to subtract more days if the last date is 0 or 6.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this does what you want:

```
select (date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month' -
        (case extract(dow from date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month')
              when 0 then 2
              when 1 then 3
              else 1
         end) * interval '1 day'
       ) as last_weekday_in_month
```

Such requests often suggest the need for a calendar table.

Comment: Nice. However this returns the last week day of the current month. OP wants the last weekday of the *last* month.